# Nuget package restore from a private feed to Jenkins workspace errors out with "(403) Forbidden"

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I am using a privately hosted Nuget server (intranet). I can restore the packages using Visual studio package manager. I can restore them using nuget.exe v2.8.5 CLI command. But when I build the JENKINS project, it throws warning on 'Restore Package' step -"**The remote server returned an error : (403) Forbidden**" and fails with the error "**Unable to find version of package**". Nuget and Jenkins are hosted on the same server on different ports. Clearing up the cache doesn't work either.

I suspect it is trying to connect to nuget.org and not the private feed. I saw the error few days back when I was trying to push a new package version to the server but had the source set to nuget.org. I changed the source and the new versions were pushed.

On the Jenkins side, the only place I could see any nuget connection is on "Nuget Publication Section" - pic1. There is no pre-build step defined for nuget restoration. Yet it was working fine before the package updates.

I tried using build step for nuget restore in Jenkins - with and without setting the "Nuget Publication" info. Still the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [NuGet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#restore) supports a _verbosity_ flag that can be set to detailed (like in `-verbosity detailed`). For config issues see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I am now able to restore packages using CLI without changing anything. Must be a cache issue. I am still struggling with the jenkins